# Census badge awardees not shown

Tags: support, badges, census

On any badge page, you can see who got that badge, sorted by date with the most recent shown first. The [census](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) badge page doesn't show any awardees. Currently, it looks like the image below:

[image: census page]

The census badge pages on other Stack Exchange sites don't show any awardees either. For example,

- [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/118/census)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1297/census)

Why is the list of awardees hidden?

Comment: Is it a privacy concern maybe?

Comment: If it only shows recents, that'd be because it's  been a year since the last time the badge was awarded

Comment: Hum, and it gets even stranger, 4 days later, Badge [`6644`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644) (= `Census`) has now completely disappeared, => "*Page not found*"...! It has also been removed from the [`Badges`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) Help Page... (It was listed (at least 4 days ago) in the "Other Badges" Section, but not anymore, and it's not mentioned either in the "Retired Badges" Section...)

Comment: Well, it's not completely gone, I still have it in my "Collection of Badges" on my own 'Profile' > 'Activity' > '[Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799241/chivracq?tab=badges&sort=name)' Tab (x5), but my *personal* [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=3799241) to the 'Census' Badge (with `/help/badges/6644/census?userid=3799241`) also yields a "Page not found"... The similar [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1973/caucus?userid=3799241) for the 'Caucus' Badge works just fine and contains all Info about for which Elections I got that one...

Comment: @chivracq I would expect your "collection of badges" link to disappear eventually. Probably just the usual issues wtih updating the database.