# Census page link is broken?

Tags: support, bug

When I clicked the “Learn more” button in my profile from recent badge section, the landing page is broken.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like they forgot to add everything back when they gave us the census badge again. [(UPDATED 5/5/23) - Changes to the Census badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/updated-5-5-23-changes-to-the-census-badge)

Comment: The Hover-Popup is a bit misleading, the *real* Msg is: "You once or more times completed the annual SO Survey between [2017-2022], we removed all Census Badges last week because of some *Privacy Issue*. Due to *High Pressure*, we are reissuing 1 Census Badge for those [2017-2022] years, no more Badges will be issued from 2023,"

Comment: "Completed the annual Stack Overflow survey one or more times; this badge can only be awarded once; your survey responses are anonymous in theory only because they _could_ be traced back with some effort and we're doing nothing against it besides removing this badge which doesn't really solve the actual issue at hand for the time being."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=7920473) is fixed and working now.

Comment: Yep indeed, and on the "main" [Census](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) page:    "*Awarded 188451 times. This badge is retired and is no longer awarded.*", OK, perfect..., but the part "*This badge can be awarded multiple times.*" is not true (anymore), as all multiple Badges were converted to just one per User.